# Putting "use strict" in a Firefox extension stops it from running but no errors shown

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I have an extension with several javascript files. When I put:

"use strict";

on some of the files the extension stops from functioning but with no error message in Error Console. However the scripts work well without 'use strict'.

My guess is that these files might be having syntax errors (that get exposed with "use strict") but don't how I can trace these errors.

Any clue highly appreciated.

Comment: It would help a lot if you could post the code here.

Answer (score 2):

Use [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/) to check for errors in your code. It has many options to configure its behavior, and can also provide style critiques, as well.

That's about all I can say without seeing your source.